# Pytest E DeprecationWarning: defusedxml.lxml is no longer supported and will be removed in a future release

Tags: python, pytest, openpyxl

I have a simple python code like these:

filename: test_pytest_openpyxl.py

```
import openpyxl

def test_1():
    print("test_1")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_1()
```

python test_pytest_openpyxl.py

it passed w/o error. However,

pytest test_pytest_openpyxl.py gave the following errors:

```
================================================= test session starts ==================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.3.3, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.1
plugins: arraydiff-0.3, astropy-header-0.1.1, doctestplus-0.5.0, openfiles-0.4.0, remotedata-0.3.2
collected 0 items / 1 error

======================================================== ERRORS ========================================================
_________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_pytest_xml.py __________________________________________
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:701: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:983: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:967: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:677: in _load_unlocked
    ???
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:143: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
C:\Users\v-jonluo\repo\performance\perf_lib\py_lib\gantt_model\pytest\test_pytest_xml.py:1: in <module>
    ???
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/__init__.py:6: in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/__init__.py:5: in <module>
    from .workbook import Workbook
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py:8: in <module>
    from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py:30: in <module>
    from openpyxl.cell import Cell, MergedCell
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/__init__.py:4: in <module>
    from .cell import Cell, WriteOnlyCell, MergedCell
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py:46: in <module>
    from openpyxl.utils.inference import (
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/utils/inference.py:10: in <module>
    from openpyxl.styles import numbers
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/__init__.py:5: in <module>
    from .alignment import Alignment
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/alignment.py:6: in <module>
    from openpyxl.descriptors import Bool, MinMax, Min, Alias, NoneSet
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/__init__.py:5: in <module>
    from .sequence import Sequence
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/sequence.py:5: in <module>
    from openpyxl.xml.functions import Element
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/xml/functions.py:31: in <module>
    from defusedxml.lxml import fromstring as _fromstring, tostring
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/defusedxml/lxml.py:29: in <module>
    stacklevel=2,
E   DeprecationWarning: defusedxml.lxml is no longer supported and will be removed in a future release.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=================================================== 1 error in 4.19s ===================================================
```

Environment:
Ubuntu 18.04/Windows 10, Pythion 3.7.4, openpyxl 2.6.2, pytest-5.3.3, setuptools                45.1.0

Answer (score 3):

This warning [has been fixed recently](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1267)

You should try a more recent version of the lib to get rid of it ([3.0.3 is available](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/))

Comment: Beat me by a minute haha!

Comment: oh yes, almost word by word same answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has been fixed in an update of `openpyxl`. See [openpyxl / openpyxl / issues / #1267 - Remove deprecation warning from defusedxml](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1267)

The latest version is 3.0.3.

Update with `pip install --force-reinstall openpyxl`.